# Как показывать текст в зависимости от ид и значения - jQuery

Tags: jquery

Подскажите пожалуйста, как в зависимости от значения показывать текст, а если значение не совпадает, показывать другой текст. Но чтобы работали вместе

```html
Если <li id="cp_id_626" class=""><span>Ваш город:</span> Москва</li>, то показывать 
<li id="cp__phone" class=""><span>Номер телефона:</span> +7777777</li>, если другой город, то показывать
<li id="cp__phone" class=""><span>Номер телефона:</span> +123456</li>
```

Есть код, но он вместе не работает

```js
function _(selector){return document.querySelector(selector);}
 
_('#cp__phone').innerHTML='<span>Номер телефона:</span> '+(_('#cp_id_626').innerHTML.indexOf('Москва')!=-1?'+7777777':'+1234567');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Оберни название города в тег `<i></i>`.

```
<li id="cp_id_626" class=""><span>Ваш город:</span> <i>Москва</i></li>

var city = $('#cp_id_626 i').text();

if (city == 'Москва') {
 $('#cp__phone').html('<span>Номер телефона:</span> +7777777');
} else {
 $('#cp__phone').html('<span>Номер телефона:</span> +123456');
}
```

Comment: Везде проставляется значение 123456, вне зависимости от cp_id_626

Comment: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vXAXWq

Comment: Хм странно, у меня наоборот работает

Comment: Из-за чего может быть?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/rsrgzg2j/

Comment: А где тег с id в разметке?

Comment: Да точно, поправил, как теперь вставлять новые города?

Comment: Такие вещи вообще на бэкэнде делаются